# Shiny R - removing/editing box borders

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shinydashboard

Very simple question (I hope!)

I'm putting together a shinyDashboard and I'm trying to edit out the grey **border-lines** which run-around Shiny boxes (see pic below - underneath the x axis label), but not had much luck as of yet.

**How can I edit the** **border-frame of these boxes**?

**Will it require CSS or is there some short-hand code to remove borders?**

[image: Screenshot of plot with grey border-line]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS. Try this:

```
 tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.box{-webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none;box-shadow: none;}')))
```